# How should I subclass this?

Tags: ios, swift, class

So I am new to programming and have a quick question. I need to subclass UIlabel in order to override draw rect in order to create some padding for my text.

How would I go about doing this? I seen answer of the subclass file but I don't know where to put it.

Should I create a brand new file in Xcode to put this class in there? I don't see anywhere else in my project where to put this.

Here is sample code from a previous answers

```
override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
      var insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 5.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 5.0)
      super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
}
```

Comment: Yes, you should create a brand new Xcode file to put it in. You could re-use an existing file, but please don't :)

Comment: @TwoStraws Ok Great! How would I apply this to my label in another class? Can you show me a code sample of doing this so I can add it to my project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to reuse the subclass a lot, creating a new swift file would be the right way to go about it.

Comment: I am going to use this for one label only as of now. I just don't know how to subclass it if I don't create another file. How would you go about doing it? thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, right-click on your project and choose New File. From the window that appears, choose "iOS" and "Source" on the left, then Cocoa Touch Class on the right. Now click Next. For "Subclass of" enter `UILabel`, then give your new subclass a name, e.g. "MyCustomLabel", and click Next then Create to create the file.

Xcode will open your new file for editing, and it will look something like this:

```
import UIKit

class MyCustomLabel: UILabel {

    /*
    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

}
```

As you can see, there's already an example `drawRect()` method in there waiting for you to upload. Put your code where that is, making sure to remove the comments as you go. Once it stops being green, it's live code.

Comment: If I follow this approach and I have a label on another viewController how would I apply it to that specific label. Sorry if this question is really novice! Thanks btw

Comment: If you're using Interface Builder, you should select the label then press Alt+Cmd+3 on your keyboard to show the Identity Inspector on the right. The first field in there is "Class", which you should change to be the name of your custom label class, e.g. MyCustomLabel. If you're not using Interface Builder, just write `MyCustomLabel(…) `rather than `UILabel(…)` in your code.